# Welches Verb gehört zu "Testfahrt"?

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Ich habe einen Wagen, den ich mag,im Autohaus gesehen. Ich möchte eine
>   Testfahrt machen, ehe ich ihn kaufen kann.

Welches Tätigkeitswort gehört zum Substantiv `Testfahrt`?

Comment: Genau das, das du selber verwendest hast: `machen`. Apropos: Ich denke, dass `Probefahrt` geläufiger ist als `Testfahrt`, wobei `Testfahrt` auch vorkommt.

Comment: Toscho- Ich mache eine Testfahrt mit(?)/ auf einem BMW. Ich mache eine Probefahrt auf/mit(?) einer Suzuki?

Comment: i think "Testfahrt" and "Probefahrt" can substitute each other in any cases in this context. In my opinion, there is no difference between both (as said, in THIS context). Opposing: Before releasing a new car, the company will make many "Testfahrten" but no "Probefahrten".. Also, when you get new tyres, the service will do a "Testfahrt" but not a "Probefahrt".

Comment: @Toscho das war ein Kommentar zu initialen Frage :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Der Wagen gefällt mir. Kann ich eine Probefahrt machen?

Möchte man dann den Wagen um den Block fahren, so spricht man von **Probe fahren** oder **eine Probefahrt machen**.

Side note:
Ein Auto ist nicht unbedingt ein Objekt, das man *mag*, nur weil man es sich mal eben angeschaut hat. Manche mögen ihr Auto mit den Jahren liebgewonnen haben und geben dem Auto sogar einen Namen, aber ein Auto, was du dir *gerade erst* angeschaut hast, kann dir 'nur' *gefallen*.